# C# UDP failed after sending failed to a udp client

Tags: c#, udp

Actually the code below is working well. the problem here is when the no one is receiving udp from the server/receiver, the upd server/receiver. the server will stop sending and receiving udp

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int receiverPort = 54679;
        UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(receiverPort);
        receiver.BeginReceive(DataReceived, receiver);
    }
    private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient c = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
        IPEndPoint receivedIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 54679);
        Byte[] receivedBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref receivedIpEndPoint);

        try
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                string _hexString = ByteArrayToString(receivedBytes).Replace(" ", "");
                TextBox1.Text = _hexString;
                string replay = "I got your message";
                byte[] replayBinary = StringToByteArray(replay);
                IPEndPoint replayIpAddress = receivedIpEndPoint;
                c.Send(replayBinary, replayBinary.Length, replayIpAddress);
            });
            c.BeginReceive(DataReceived, ar.AsyncState);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception in you null catch?  A connection is start by the client and your code will not send until a client connects.  Once the client disconnects the UdpClient will become null.  To keep code running you must add an event for the disconnect and then create a new UdpClient and run the BeinReceive() method.

Comment: I try to catch the send method, but it it doesn't fall on the exception.

Comment: You are never sending because you haven't received any data.  Once the first client disconnects your client stops listening.  You have to capture the connection close event and then start a new client to listen for new connection.